# Problema instalando composer para Laravel

Tags: laravel, composer

Estoy instalando el composer y me sale este error

> The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded:
>   failed to open stream: Solo se permite un uso de cada dirección de
>   socket (protocolo/dirección de red/puerto)

A que se debe? Como puedo solucionarlo?

Estoy usando  proxy, no se si tenga algo que ver.

Answer (score 0):

yo supongo que usastes este comando para intentar instarlo :

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

posiblemente tu error es similar a este :

```
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(https://getcomposer.org/versions): failed to open stream: Connection timed out in - on line 762
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in - on line 508
None of the 0 stable version(s) of Composer matches your PHP version (5.4.45 / ID: 50445)
```

si este es tu caso existen dos posibles soluciones :

> Creo que podrían ser problemas de proxy. Eliminar los vars de entorno https_proxy y http_proxy deberia funcionar para  (Windows 10). Y luego, instalalos de nuevo, establece el proxy en blanco. Debería funcionar

o Cambié de https a http:

```
curl -sS http://getcomposer.org/installer%20| php
```

Comment: sería mejor sugerir al usuario que proporcione mas información en su pregunta en vez de asumir pues es algo que no conocemos

Comment: @AlfredoPaz ps tienes razon, el motivo que respondi asi es que yo tuve el mismo problema hace tiempo